# Is this overfitting ? Make validation loss more stable

Tags: neural-networks

This is my training and validation loss on 5-fold CV for a classification task. Is this overfitting ?

I’m using Focal Loss, AdamW(lr=1e-3, weight_decay=0.01), and ReduceLROnPlateau(factor=0.5, patience=3). What I can do to make validation loss more stable (another optimizer or lr_cheduler or anything) ? Thank you !

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: This is likely very problem-dependent. What methods for reducing overfitting have you tried? I found a decent overview of some regularization techniques here: https://www.kaggle.com/sid321axn/regularization-techniques-in-deep-learning

Comment: I just use weight decay in AdamW